# Let $A$ be the set of all natural numbers less than or equal to $100$. How many relations can be defined in $A \times A$ such that (details inside)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, relations

$A = \{x \le100, x \in \mathbb{N}\}$

How many relations $R \subseteq A \times A$ can be defined such that R is reflexive, R is symmetric and $(2,x) \in R \Leftrightarrow x $ is an even number

If you could explain step by step I'd be really grateful

Comment: I was going to try to start from ALL the possible relations, and then substract all those that don't meet the requirements. However, the total of relations is $2^{10000}$ (if I'm not mistaken) and it's a number too big for me to work with (I'm a first year student and we don't usualy handle numbers a scientific calculator can't handle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's figure out which elements of $A \times A$ are bounded to be in or out of $R$, and which ones aren't.

- Because of the last condition, every couple of the form $(2, \: x)$ with $x$ even is necessarily in $R$; but then, because of the symmetry, $(x, \: 2)$ is in $R$ too.
- Since $R$ is reflexive, $(x, \: x)$ is always in $R$.
- Again from the last property, $(2, \: x) \not\in R$ whenever $x$ is odd. Also, because of the symmetry, $(x, \: 2) \not\in R$.
- We are left with the couples $(x, \: y)$ with $x \ne y$ and $x, \: y \ne 2$, for which we are (almost) arbitrarily allowed to decide whether they belong or not to $R$. The only condition that has to be satisfied is the symmetry, so $(x, \: y) \in R$ iff $(y, \: x) \in R$.

Summing up, the number of relations that satisfy all the conditions matches the number of ways in which we can choose, for every *unordered* couple $\{x, \: y\}$ with $x \ne y$ and $x, \: y \ne 2$ (and of course $1 \le x, \: y \le 100$), if $(x, \: y) \in R$ or $(x, \: y) \ne R$. Since such couples are $\displaystyle \binom{99}{2} = 4851$, the number of relations is $\boxed{2^{4851}}$.

Comment: Thanks! After 5 minutes of reading this again and again, I finally get how to do it. Again, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Since $R$ is reflexive every pair on main diagonal is in $R$.

Since $R$ is symmetric the upper part over the main diagonal is uniquely determined by lover part under the main diagonal we must count free ''places'' in lover part. Since the pairs $(4,2),$ $(6,2)$,...$(100,2)$ are in lover part and  the pairs $(2,1)$, $(3,2), (5,2)$,...,$(99,2)$ are not, we have ${100^2-100 \over 2} -99= 4851$ pairs to choose in lover part. Thus we have $2^{4851}$ relations $R$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's think it out.

$A \times A$ have $100*100= 10000$ elements of which each either is or is not in the relationship.  So there are $2^{10000}$ relations.

But it is symmetric.   $(a,b)$ is in the relation if and only if $(b,a)$, so we don't so we only have to consider whether pairs $(a,b); a\le b$ are in the relationship.  That will "force" whether $(b,a)$ is in.

There are $\sum_{i=1}^{100} i = 5050$ such pairs so there are $2^{5050}$ symetric relations.  But the relation is also reflexive so all $(a,a)$ are forced to be in.  So the only "free" pairs are $(a,b); a < b$ and there are are $100$ $(a,a)$ pairs so we have $5050 - 100 = 4950$ free pairs.

We also told that the pair $(2,x)$ is not free.  It actually doesn't matter if $(2,x)$ is forced to be in or $(2,x)$ is force to be out.  It is just that $(2,x)$ is forced.  And if $(2,x)$ is forced so is $(x,2)$.

So let's review which pairs are free.

$(a,b)$ is free if i) $a \ne b$ [$(a,a)$ *must* be in] ii) wolog $a < b$.  [If $a > b$ then $(a,b)$ is forced to be what $(b,a)$ is.]  iii) neither $a$ nor $b$ is equal to $2$.  [$(2,b)$ is forced to be in or out.]

So there are $\sum_{b=1;b\ne 2}^{100} |A=\{a|a<b; a\ne 2\}| =$

$\sum_{c=1}^{99} |D=\{d|d < c\}|$

$\sum_{c=1}^{99} (c-1)$

$\sum_{e=0}^{98} e = \frac {98*99}2 = 4851$

and the number of such  relations is $2^{4851}$.

=====

I'm not going to change my answer but lashes with a wet noodle to me for viewing this in terms of summation rather than the more intuitive "choosing".  In choosing a pair $(a,b)$ we are choosing two distinct terms (because $(a,a)$ must be in the relation) from $99$ choices ($2$ is omitted because $(2,x)$ and $(y,2)$ are forced to be in or out base on the other term) and order doesn't matter (because $(a,b)$ is in $\iff$ $(b,a)$ is in).

There are ${99\choose 2}=4851$ such pairs.

Same answer, same reason.  But "choice" is maybe more intuitive and easy to follow than summation.  (Although they are equivalent yet different models for the same thing.)

Comment: I wish I knew how summation works tbh. I've only seen choosing so far. Still, thanks for your time

Comment: Summation is straight forward.  $b$ can be anything from $1$ to $100$ (but not $2$) so you add up all the options if $b$ is $1$ plus the options if $b$ is $3$ plus the options if $b$ is 4 .... etc.  $a$ can be anything less than $b$ so that is b -1.  So you are adding $0$ (b=1) $+1$ (b=3,a=1) $+2$(b=4;a=1,3) $+........ +53$ (b=55; a=1,3....54)$+ 54+ ...... + 98$(b=100, a=1,3....99) to get all possible options.  Note: ${n \choose 2}= 1 + 2 +3+.......... + (n-1)$.  By stars and bars we can give a physical argument why that would be true.